mongodb query $match if tenary to field
i have a query in mongodb, i want to get from collection by specific field the field is "private.group" and its boolean.
i want the $match will be dynamic to pass is as varible (pass is true or false) and then make this query work as private group or public group.
how can i make this if tenary work in $match?
i can pass parameter to the function but its not work with if tenary
i mean this line of group.private
export const getAllPrivateGroupsData = async (
    userId: string,

    pagination: Pagination
) => {
    const pipeline = [
        {
            $match: {
                userId: userId,
                groupId: { $exists: true },
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "groups",
                localField: "groupId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "group",
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$group",
        },

        {
            $match: {
                "group.private": true, // Filter only public groups
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "events",
                localField: "group.eventsIds",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "events",
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$events",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "event_images",
                localField: "events.images",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "eventImages",
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "event_comments",
                localField: "events.comments",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "eventComments",
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "event_members",
                localField: "events._id",
                foreignField: "eventId",
                as: "eventMembers",
            },
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$group._id",
                name: { $first: "$group.name" },
                imageCover: { $first: "$group.imageCover" },
                private: { $first: "$group.private" },
                createdAt: { $first: "$group.createdAt" },
                admin: { $first: "$group.admin" },
                status: { $first: "$status" },
                neighborhood: { $first: "$group.neighborhood" },
                institution: { $first: "$group.institution" },
                description: { $first: "$group.description" },

                events: {
                    $push: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            {
                                userType: {
                                    $cond: {
                                        if: {
                                            $in: [
                                                userId,
                                                "$eventMembers.userId",
                                            ],
                                        },
                                        then: "member",
                                        else: "visitor",
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            "$events",
                            { images: "$eventImages" },
                            { comments: "$eventComments" },
                            { eventMembers: "$eventMembers" },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    ]
    return await DB.withPagination(
        DB.db?.collection("group_members").aggregate(pipeline),
        pagination
    )?.toArray()
}


why cant you pass a variable like "group.private": value, i dont think i got the question

Can not just pass a third parameter into your function like getAllPrivateGroupsData(userId,  pagination,  trueOrFalse).

Its weird but, when i pass boolean parameter to group.private : variable its not working, its reutn true even if the varible is false, and i console log the variable i saw its false and still gave me the true documents, are you sure this is the way to change the variable? Because i tried it a few times and its not working only if i change it manually to true or false but ad dynamic parameter its not working and give me only one even if the value is the opposite

If you share some sample documents from the collections you are querying then someone will be able to help you debug the actual problem
